# Recursive algorithm stops working after certain depth

Tags: java, math, recursion, integer, biginteger

I was exploring Fork/Join framework and its possible speed benefits through factorial counting, when discovered that my sequential recursive algorithm breaks at a certain point. To be precise, when I try to count `46342!` the result from `RecursiveCounter` is wrong, but before that value it is always right and is the same that result from `ParallelCounter` and `LoopCounter`. Does anyone have an idea why that may happen?

Here are the classes:

RecursiveCounter:

```
public class RecursiveCounter implements FactorialCounter, RangeFactorialCounter {
    @Override
    public BigInteger count(int number) {
        return count(1, number);
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger count(int from, int to) {
        int middle = (from + to) >> 1;
        BigInteger left;
        BigInteger right;
        if (middle - from > 1)
            left = count(from, middle);
        else
            left = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(from * middle));
        if (to - (middle + 1) > 1)
            right = count(middle + 1, to);
        else
            right = to == middle + 1 ? new BigInteger(String.valueOf(to)) : new BigInteger(String.valueOf((middle + 1) * to));
        return left.multiply(right);
    }
}
```

LoopCounter:

```
public class LoopCounter implements FactorialCounter, RangeFactorialCounter {
    @Override
    public BigInteger count(final int number) {
        return count(1, number);
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger count(final int from, final int to) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        for (int i = from; i < to + 1; i++) {
            result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

A RecursiveTask for ParallelCounter:

```
public class FactorialTask extends RecursiveTask<BigInteger> {
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private RangeFactorialCounter iterativeCounter = new LoopCounter();

    private Integer firstVal;
    private Integer lastVal;

    public FactorialTask(Integer from, Integer to) {
        super();
        this.firstVal = from;
        this.lastVal = to;
    }

    @Override
    protected BigInteger compute() {
        return count(firstVal, lastVal);
    }

    private BigInteger count(int from, int to) {
        int middle = (from + to) >> 1;
        if (to - from > THRESHOLD) {
            List<FactorialTask> tasks = Arrays.asList(new FactorialTask(from, middle), new FactorialTask(middle + 1, to));
            tasks.forEach(RecursiveTask::fork);
            return tasks.stream()
                    .map(RecursiveTask::join)
                    .map(BigInteger.class::cast)
                    .reduce(new BigInteger("1"), BigInteger::multiply);
        } else {
            return (from != to) ? countSequential(from, to) : new BigInteger(String.valueOf(from));
        }
    }

    private BigInteger countSequential(int from, int to) {
        return iterativeCounter.count(from, to);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result ? it may exceed `BigInteger` max value.

Comment: @c0der I doubt it does, because other two implementations return same result, which is also a correct one. And `BigInteger` bound is pretty high to be honest, 2^(2^31) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @c0der `BigInteger` can contain up to `~10^646456993` digits, but `46342!` is only `~10^196107` digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `RecursiveCounter`, `from * middle` and `(middle + 1) * to` might overflow, you need use `BigInteger` to manipulate them:

```
...
left = BigInteger.valueOf(from).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(middle));
...
right = to == middle + 1 ? BigInteger.valueOf(to) : BigInteger.valueOf(to).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(middle + 1));
```

Then you can get the same result in `RecursiveCounter` and `LoopCounter`:

```
LoopCounter loopCounter = new LoopCounter();
RecursiveCounter recursiveCounter = new RecursiveCounter();
BigInteger loopResult = loopCounter.count(46342);
BigInteger recursiveResult = recursiveCounter.count(46342);
System.out.println(loopResult.equals(recursiveResult)); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of numeric overflow of an `int`, not because of recursive depth, which is nicely controlled by your algorithm, which needs O(log<sub>2</sub>n) stack frames for recursion.

The overflow happens here:

```
new BigInteger(String.valueOf((middle + 1) * to))
```

When `to` is high, this value can overflow `int`. Specifically, when `middle` approaches `to` in the second "leg" of recursive invocations, you multiply `46341` by `46342`, which yields `-2147432674` due to an overflow ([demo](https://ideone.com/U2jaed)).

You can fix this by using only `BigInteger` for "payload" multiplication, i.e.

```
BigInteger.valueOf(middle+1).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(to))
```